# Error passing parameters through haskell function

Tags: haskell

I'm receiving an error and don't know why.

```
mapo :: ((Float, Float) -> Float) -> [(Float, Float)] -> [Float]
mapo f [] = []
mapo f (x:y) = f x : mapo f y
```

Compiles ok.

```
*Main> mapo + [(1,2)]

Couldn't match type `(Float, Float) -> (Float, Float)' with `Float'
Expected type: (Float, Float) -> Float
  Actual type: (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float)
In the first argument of `mapo', namely `(+)'
In the expression: mapo (+) [(1, 2)]
In an equation for `it': it = mapo (+) [(1, 2)]
```

The purpose of this function is to receive an operator (let's say `+` or `-`), a list of pairs of numbers (`Float`) and return the result of using that operator with each of the pairs of parameters of the list.

Comment: Please change the title of your question. "What am I doing wrong" doesn't tell anyone anything about the contents of your question.

Comment: You are right, i changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is merely a syntactic error; When you want to partially apply an operator you need to wrap it in parentheses; So instead of

```
mapo + [(1,2)]
```

write

```
mapo (+) [(1,2)]
```

Otherwise it parses as adding `mapo` to `[(1,2)]` (i.e. `(+) mapo [(1,2)]` which is clearly not what you want.

Next thing is getting the type right:

`(+) :: Float -> Float -> Float` (in your case, its real type is more general) - but your function wants `(Float,Float) -> Float`. These two types aren't equal, but they express pretty much the same thing so you can easily map between them with the `curry :: ((a,b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c` and `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c` functions. In this case you need to pass `uncurry (+)` to your `mapo` function.

Comment: It won't. That's what the second part of the answer is for.

Comment: Thanks @Cubic! Another question. Lets say that i dont wont to use uncurry and i can change the function...if i change it to `mapo::(Float->Float->Float)->[(Float,Float)]->[Float]` Im receiving an error at compile time. How would you do it?

Comment: Just do the uncurry in `mapo`.

Answer (score 1):

`(+)` does not have type `(Float, Float) -> Float`, but `uncurry (+)` does:

```
mapo (uncurry (+)) [(1,2)]

-> [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*Main> mapo (\(a,b) -> a+b) [(1,2)]
[3.0]
```

Your problem is that mapo expects a function of the tuple `(Float,Float)` but addition is a function on two `Floats`, rather than a tuple.

```
*Main> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

You can use `mapo` as-is, as long as you remember to pass it a function which expects `(Float,Float)` and returns `Float`.